# Clarify this Python regex and debug information

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
>>> rr = re.compile(u"[\24C2]+", re.DEBUG)
max_repeat 1 4294967295
  in
    literal 20
    literal 67
    literal 50
```

By mistake, instead of `\u24C2` I entered `\24C2` in the regex above. While debugging I was trying to understand the debug output. In the output above what does `literal 20`, `literal 67` and `literal 50` mean ? And where did they come from ?

Answer (score 2):

The literal comes from the ordinal representation of the characters (or integer value of the unicode codepoints for a unicode string) within the specified range in the specified regex pattern.

```
>>> chr(20)
'\x14'
>>> chr(67)
'C'
>>> chr(50)
'2'
```

If you are confused as to why there is a `'\x14'`, it came from `'\24'` which is the octal representation of the integer `20`, or hex `0x14`.

```
>>> '\24'
'\x14'
```

Correcting this to what you said you originally wanted to do:

```
>>> rr = re.compile(u"[\u24C2]+", re.DEBUG)
max_repeat 1 4294967295
  literal 9410
```

Now there is only one literal 9410 or the integer representation of the unicode codepoint that will be matched.

Comment: You may want to clarify the first one, so that it's obvious how that number came about.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Hah, you beat me to finishing the edit.